# Magento 2.2.6 Configurable Product How to Show Old Price and Special Price?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, magento2.2.6

I have used Magento 2.2.6 version. I have one configurable product. I have added a special price to the associated product.The Special Price is Display but the old price is not displayed on how to show them?

Please refer the following screenshot:

**In Frontend:**

[image: Magento 2.2.6 Configurable Product How to Show Old Price and Special Price]

**In admin Special Price:**

[image: Magento 2.2.6 Configurable Product How to Show Old Price and Special Price]

**In admin Product add/edit area:**

[image: Magento 2.2.6 Configurable Product How to Show Old Price and Special Price]

Answer (score 12):

Found solution [Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7624)

Copy `final_price.phtml` from

**Vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

to

**Vendor/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

change (around line 22)

```
<?php if (!$block->isProductList() && $block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

**with**

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

(**special_price** will display)

and replace

```
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">
```

by

```
<span class="old-price sly-old-price">
```

(remove the **no-display** class)

Comment: Fixed the same issue from Magento 2.3.2. Thanks

Comment: This solution does not work if only some product variants have a special price. In this case the same price is displayed twice, which looks weird.

Comment: @hashbang did you find any solution?... i have the same issue when only one child product has a special price !

Comment: @hashbang did you find solutions for this? because i am also getting same issue

Comment: @Medomage  did you find solutions for this? because I am also getting the same issue