# regular price only when sppecial price is not set in configurable product magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I am able to show the regular price and special price for the configurable product but when special price is not set than the regular price is showing two time
I am using magento2, please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Please refer to the [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/267096)

Comment: Hi Pratik, Thanks for helping I am able to show the regular price and special price but there is one case when the special price is not set for 1 attribute, for example, I have 4 color I have set a special price for 3 colors but not for 4th color in this case on 4 color selection its showing regular price and final price both I want to show only one price in this case

Comment: Please add your updated/custom code in description. Also check above scenario in the default Magento setup(with sample data).